# SSL certificate for a subdomain hosted remotely

Tags: ssl-certificate

Scenario: Suppose www.test.com is a domain that exists and I want to handle requests for widgets.test.com on my webserver. I work with their administrator and adjust their DNS record to point widgets.test.com to an IP address on my webserver.

Question: If I want to handle https requests for that subdomain, do I purchase the SSL cert for widgets.test.com and install on my webserver? Or, does a cert have to be purchased for the top level domain and installed on the primary webserver?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be purchased for the main domain, you can purchase an SSL cert for a specific subdomain. SSL certs are keyed to the exact domain that you specify, so if you purchase one for "https://*.mysite.com" that's a different cert than for "https://mysite.com".

If you want to get an SSL certificate that would cover both, you might want to look into purchasing something like a Wildcard SSL certificate.

Comment: What if the primary test.com domain does not want SSL? Do I install the subdomain cert on my webserver?

Comment: Yeah, I think that should be fine. In that case, you could get a normal SSL cert keyed to the subdomain you want and you should be able to use it as long as you can show ownership of it in some way.

Comment: I got an answer from support at digicert. The owner of test.com would have to approve the purchase of the cert through an email that is sent out when the SSL order is placed.